# Accept question mark on .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I want to accept the question mark on my URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/page/url-example-?-15
```

I use this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule page/([a-zA-Z0-9éèÉàêç\-\"\'\(\)\:\!\?]+)-([0-9]+) page.php?url=$1&Id=$2
```

All characters work except the question mark, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Not possible `?` is a url metacharacter, signifying the start of query parameters.that url will parse as url `http://www.example.com/page/url-example-`, with a query string of `-15`.  The `?` would have to encoded as `%3F` to become a LITERAL `?` in the url, and not a metachar.

Comment: the `?` has a special meaning in URL strings. Why on Earth would you want to fight against that standard? Can't you choose a different character?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9éèÉàêç\-\"\'\(\)\:\!\?]+)-([0-9]+)/", 
             "url-example-?-15", 
             $matches, 
             PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

  print_r($matches);

?>
```

```css
body, html, iframe { 
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  overflow: hidden ;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://ideone.com/1yr1ec"></iframe>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.